# Display Brightness

Tags: 11.10, display, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I adjust brightness settings when I am on battery?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79730/how-can-i-adjust-brightness-settings-when-i-am-on-battery)

I remember that in Windows you could put a different Display Brightness when I was on battery in my laptop, and a different one when I was connected to the AC source. This can be done in ubuntu without having to change manually the brightness? Thanks 4all!